# How to make an arraylist of arraylists parcelable in android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, parcelable

My problem is that I have an arraylist of arraylists with custom objects that needs to be passed from one activity to another.

Clearly, let's say I have something like:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Statement>> data;
```

in one activity and I want to pass it to another. So, first what I have done is to make **Statement** implement the **Parcelable** class. 
Then in the first activity (sender) I call the **putExtra()** method by passing it the **data**. 
In the second activity (receiver) I call the **getSerializableExtra()** method to get **data**.

That works. But I have read that Parcelable would be better for efficiency etc. and so I tried to call **putParcelableArrayListExtra()** in the sender activity and the **getParcelableArrayListExtra()** method on the receiver activity. 
But when I do that, I get red underlines indicating sth. like

> ArrayList< android.os.Parcelable > is required

in the first activity which is the sender I have the line:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);

intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(SenderActivity.EXTRA_LISTOFSTATEMENTLISTS, dataListOfStatementLists);
```

In the receiver activity I have sth. like:

```
myList = ( ArrayList<ArrayList<Statement>>) getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_LISTOFSTATEMENTLISTS);
```

What I need to fix ? I know the basics about how to send Parcelable objects from one activity to another. But that was all things like

```
ArrayList<ParcelableObject> data
```

I have never done it for nested data like this

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<ParcelableObject>>
```

I hope someone can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just wrap the list inside an object which is parcelable.

Answer (score 1):

This is just another way to do it. I suppose you know how to get the values in other activity.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Statement>> data;
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putInt("size", data.size());
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("item"+i, data.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this to send Data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(SenderActivity.this, ReceiverActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("object", List);
in.putExtra("list", bundle);
startActivity(in);
```

For Recieving Data

```
Intent i=getIntent();
Bundle bundle= i.getBundleExtra("list");
ArrayList<Statement> list = bundle.getParcelable("object");
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to pass data from one activity to another one via `Intent` you have to make sure that the classes where you create the objects that you want to send are implementing `Serializable`, otherwise it won't work. Your problem could be something related to this so I recommend you to implement `Serializable` on your classes.